# Multithreading executing multiple tasks in parallel in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift4, dispatch-queue

I know creation of queues and able to execute single task but how can i execute multiple tasks in parallel.

Concurrent Queue ---->

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.some.concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
concurrentQueue.async {
    //executable code

}
```

BackgroundQueue without priorities default--->

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    //executable code
}
```

Backgroundqueue with priorities---->

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { //.userInteractive .background .default .unspecified
    //executable code
}
```

Getting back to the main Queue ---->

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     //executable code
}
```

All are asynchronous but how can i execute multiple methods at a time how should i code in swift.

Comment: Please don't try to remove your question by editing the question text. If you have a legitimate reason to want the question removed, you should ask a moderator or site admin for help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305484/how-to-delete-my-own-noisy-questions-that-have-answers for more information.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a for loop method that calls a method and you want to calls this methods concurrent, so just use this :

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: Int, execute: { (count) in
   doSomethingFor(count: count)
}
```

But if you have some individuals methods that you want to call concurrent, just do like this:

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.some.concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

concurrentQueue.async {
    //executable code
    myFirstMethod()
}

concurrentQueue.async {
    //executable code
       mySecondMethod()
}
```

This way concurrentQueue, will manages your tasks concurrently itself.

Comment: Its hard to handle this by `DispatchQeue`. Instead you could use `Operation` and `OperationQeueu`. In that situation you can set maximum Concurrent tasks that is what you want.

Comment: It's beyond of here to explain it, but if you want a good tutorial  about that just have look at this tutorial:

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency/